# Как в Windows 10 убрать с экрана след от программы после её крэша не выходя из системы?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Практически в любой версии Windows есть неприятный глюк в виде следа от окна вылетевшего по ошибке приложения. Windows 10 не стала в этом смысле исключением:

[[image: Пример такого поведения1]
Перезапуск Windows Explorer не помогает.

Вопрос: как избавиться от этого следа в Windows 10, не прибегая к кардинальным мерам, как то: выход из системы, ребут и т.д.

Comment: попробуй вызвать диспетчер задач и во вкладке процессы поискать ту программу которая выдала ошЫбку =), заверши её процесс

Comment: В том-то и дело, что после крэша программы, её нет в диспетчере задач! Такое ощущение, что фрейм-буфер Windows забит неправильными данными...